# FreeSync vs. VRB Performance difference

Tags: display

I am using **Acer KA242Y** with 75Hz and 1ms response time. Just wondering what type of performance or setting for better long-term use. My eyes are easy to get tired and need smooth graphical performance, so I tried the performance setting and recording wih my phone (60fps video).

FreeSync : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YZNE7u97DmBTMmKpMl05QnBFDOIooerY/view?usp=sharing

VRB : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sL0IxkzIo1xw5L24f-PVN0wi8KxT8SCl/view?usp=sharing

*NB : cannot do both FreeSync and VRB On*

I noticed **VRB** have moving lines (or whatever the right term called) in Normal Mode and Extreme Mode and ***it gets darker***, I know the lines is not noticable with human eyes but, but is that normal for VRB?

With **FreeSync** there is no moving lines.

- Is FreeSync way superior than VRB? or maybe they have different type of performance?
- Which mode is good for long term use?

Answer (score 0):

to give you brief explanation vrb when set to the max you basically tapping that 1ms because at it default its preatty sure it 4ms or 6ms someone correct me please as freesync stays at the 4ms or 6ms  but makes gameplay more smoother and clearer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).